# Divide value in column if greater than x

Tags: r

Below is a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
ID <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4))
LKUP <- c(2, 4, 10, 25, 17, 18, 6, 3)
df <- data.frame(ID, LKUP)

ID LKUP
A  2
A  4
A  10 
A  25
B  17
B  18
B  6
B  3
```

I want to divide the LKUP column by 2, but only if the value is greater than 10.

The output should be:

```
ID LKUP
A  2
A  4
A  10 
A  12.5
B  8.5
B  9
B  6
B  3
```

The ID column doesn't matter, but I do need to keep it in the final output.

This seems simple (and probably is), but I'm new to R and can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: If there are any ways I could have improved the question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
df1$LKUP <- with(df1, ifelse(LKUP > 10, LKUP/2, LKUP))
```

---

Or  with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[LKUP > 10, LKUP := LKUP/2][]
```

NOTE: Make sure that the 'LKUP' is `numeric` class

Answer (score 3):

```
df$LKUP[df$LKUP > 10] <- df$LKUP[df$LKUP > 10] / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`'s `mutate()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(LKUP = ifelse(LKUP > 10, LKUP/2, LKUP))

# ID LKUP
# 1  A  2.0
# 2  A  4.0
# 3  A 10.0
# 4  A 12.5
# 5  B  8.5
# 6  B  9.0
# 7  B  6.0
# 8  B  3.0
```